# Get to system restore without loading USB keyboard or mouse drivers?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, drivers, keyboard, system-restore

My windows 8.1 pro system has been running great, and I should have left everything alone, but after installing a new graphics card, I thought I'd go ahead and update other drivers.  I made system restore points and updated the USB 3.0 drivers, then restarted.  System restarts fine, but keyboard and mouse are not responsive.

RDP is disabled.
PC is on LAN, but I don't know it's IP.

All I'm able to do is hard restart with the reset button.
Keyboard works until Windows starts, so I can do whatever until then...

How do I get into system restore mode (before the new USB drivers kick in and disable keyboard and mouse) to roll back to the restore point?

Comment: Except I can't get into safe mode with F8 ... tried 5 times already.

Comment: Why do people go out of their way to "update" USB drivers?  If USB devices are working, why touch the driver, it's not like new functionality will happen

Comment: "Except I can't get into safe mode with F8 ... tried 5 times already" - This is because your using Windows 8.1, manually cause Windows to fail to boot three times, the fourth attempt will throw you into the Advanced Startup.